# how can I get list the labels of the selected check boxes in ruby/rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I am trying to get the values of the selected check boxes to show up in a view.

Here is my controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

    def new 
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)
        @post.save
        redirect_to @post
    end

    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end 

    def index
        @posts = Post.all
    end 

private
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:check_box, :label, :id, :title, :text)
    end

end
```

Here is my new.html.erb file:

```
<h1>SWORD Mock Device Page</h1>

<%= form_for (:post), url: posts_path do |f| %>
    <p>
        <h2>Android Phones</h2>
        <%= f.check_box(:razr_max1) %>
        <%= f.label(:razr_max1, "Droid Razr Max #1") %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.check_box(:galaxyS2) %>
        <%= f.label(:galaxyS2, "Samsung Galaxy S2") %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <h2>Android Tablets</h2>
        <%= f.check_box(:asusprime3) %>
        <%= f.label(:asusprime3, "Asus Transormer Prime #3") %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.check_box(:motoxoom1) %>
        <%= f.label(:motoxoom1, "Motorola Xoom #1") %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%=f.submit "Select" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

And here is my show.html.erb file that i want to display the values (labels) of the checked selections:

```
<p>
  <strong>Device(s) chosen:</strong>
  <%= @post.title %>
  <%= @post.id %>
</p>
```

Now -- I am very new to ruby/rails and need some really solid and explained answers and examples. Forgive me for this very simple and basic question.

Much thanks!!

ironmantis7x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You have to edit your model association  a bit,as your design does not seem good :)

#### Create a model  Device with name, category columns.

```
rails g model Device name category
```

#### Create a join table:

```
rails g migration CreateDevicesPostsJoinTable
```

#### Update the generated file with the following:

```
class CreateDevicesPostsJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :devices_posts, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :post_id
      t.integer :device_id
    end
  end
 end
```

#### in Post model add:

`has_and_belongs_to_many :devices`

#### in _form

```
<h1>SWORD Mock Device Page</h1>

<%= form_for (:post), url: posts_path do |f| %>
  <p> 
  <%=f.label :title%>
   <%=f.text_field :title%>
  </p>    
<p>
   <h2>Android Phones</h2>
   <% Device.all.each do |device| %>
   <div>
     <%= check_box_tag "post[device_ids][]", device.id, @post.devices.include?(device) %>
     <%= device.name %>
   </div>
   <% end %>

</p>
```

#### in posts controller's update action:

```
def update
    params[:post][:device_ids] ||= []  #to unset all the devices
    #...
  end
```

#### show.html.erb

```
<h2> <%= @post.title %></h2>
  <p>
  <strong>Device(s) chosen:</strong>
  <ul>
   <%@post.devices.each do |device|%>
     <li> <%= device.name%> </li>
   <%end%>
  </ul>
  </p>
```

Comment: thank you ... I am ready and willing to learn!  I just picked up a rails book literally today!

Comment: run `rails g migration CreateDevicesPostsJoinTable`. This will create a file under db/migrate directory.

replace that file content with : 

`class CreateDevicesPostsJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :devices_posts, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :post_id
      t.integer :device_id
    end
  end
 end`

Comment: I get an error in the new.html.erb file: 

Showing /Users/user/rails_projects/SWORDMock_dev/app/views/posts/new.html.erb where line #18 raised:

/Users/user/rails_projects/SWORDMock_dev/app/views/posts/new.html.erb:18: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end
/Users/user/rails_projects/SWORDMock_dev/app/views/posts/new.html.erb:20: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end

Comment: I am not seeing where the check boxes are defined and displayed?  Am I missing something????

Comment: join here:

http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32454/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-17334480

Comment: Very helpful answer !